# HTML - nested td tags

Tags: html, css

I wrote this little piece of HTML:

```
<table><tr><td>1</td><td style="display:none"><td>2</td> <td>3</td></td></tr> <table>
```

As you can see the td tags containing "2" and "3" are inside the `display:none` td tag.

I this valid HTML?

The W3 validator did not complain, but the browser(both chrome and firefox) is re-organizing the tags this way:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td style="display:none"></td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I see this with inspect element. When I view the page source it is in the original form. Why is the browser doing this? Is it valid or not?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, why all the downvotes? Doesn't seem like that bad a question to me

Comment: Down-voters - please explain...

Comment: This is a great question with an epic answer - no td nesting!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> As you can see the td tags containing "2" and "3" are inside the `display:none` td tag.

No, they aren't. The end tag for a td element is optional. You cannot have a td element inside another td element. The second td start tag implicitly closes the previous td element.

> I this valid HTML?

Omitting the end tag is. Having an end tag immediately after another end tag is not (since you can't end an element that isn't open).

> The W3 validator did not complain

It does when I use it.

HTML5: Stray end tag td

HTML4: end tag for element "TD" which is not open

Answer (score 2):

it's not valid because you've got nested `<td>` tags....

`<td style="display:none"><td>2`

You can't place a table cell inside a table cell. A table cell is only valid inside a table row. In other words, `<td>` can *never* be preceded by `<td>`.

This would be correct:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td style="display:none;">2</td>
<td style="display:none;">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried nesting a table inside a TD?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>E</td>
          <td>F</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```